# Proper order of valves in heating pump systems?

Tags: plumbing, water, valve, pump, floorheating

I believe I have a basic understanding of the usage of each component. That being said, I lack knowledge of the proper installation order, especially regarding non-return valves (among others).

I have a splitter-type heat pump unit [Daikin Altehrma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N00v5.jpg) that is a bit weak for my system so the manufacturer recommends the usage of additional components for a correct operation:

- anuloid (hydraulic balancer of dynamic pressures)
- magnetic filter (because the internal is weak)
- secondary pump (because the internal is weak)
- and expansion tanks (for cold and hot water)

Here is a diagram I made of how things I imagine should be connected, but I have doubts if it makes sense:

---

[image]

---

I'm looking to know if the positions of **non-return valves**, **air vents**, **filters** and **pressure by-pass valve** are correct. I even tried to ask ChatGPT, but unfortunately, I was able to force the order upon AI even in a malicious way so I guess I will need a piece of advice from an actual living human being.

Cold, hot, and re-circulation outlets are 3/4" while outlets for underfloor heating are 1". The pressure by-pass valve was supplied with the unit and "in and out" are both 3/4" so I assume this should be installed either on a hot or cold outlet (?) - no idea.

Comment: You do not need air vents in cold lines only in hot

Comment: You do not need expansion tank in the cold line, only in hot

Comment: @Ruskes air vents on both cold lines are an inseparable part (feature) of the filter itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear as to why you need 2 expansion tanks in the first place, but even if you did use both, it doesn't make sense, to me, where the one on the cold water line is located and why you don't have it in the same position as the one on the hot water line. Having a non-return valve placed in between the tank and the cold water side expansion tank renders the expansion tank useless.

I only install expansion tanks on the cold water line side but I know others install them on the hot water side.

Pressure bypass valves are generally placed at the outlet of a pump to recirculate some of the liquid back into the reservoir it is pumping out of so I am not understanding your intended use of it in your cold water inlet line to your tank?

Comment: `why you don't have it in the same position as the one on the hot water line` - not sure what you mean by this. from your proposed answer I understood this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1V4.png is that correct?

Comment: The expansion tank on the cold water side has to be the closest item to the tank like it is on the hot water side.